# "Одни мама с дочкой" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

Уверен, что можно сказать *одна,* но можно ли во множественном числе? *Одни* в смысле *определённые,* но скорее всего незнакомые слушателю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Уверен, что можно сказать одна, но можно ли во множественном числе?
>   Одни в смысле определённые, но скорее всего незнакомые слушателю.

Можно. Конструкция типа "А с Б" допускает согласование во множественном числе ("Шли Петя с Сашей"). Но в данном случае я не вижу в том большого смысла. Разница между множественным и единственным числом здесь в том, что при множественном оба объекта ставятся как бы на один уровень важности, или близкий к нему (сравните: "шел охотник с собакой", но "шли Король с Королевой"). Поэтому "Одни мама с дочкой" выражало бы одинаковое отношение к маме и дочке, но в таком контексте это совершенно не принципиально.

То, о чем пытается заявить oleedd (сами по себе, без посторонних), до некоторой степени справедливо, но это ж не то значение, о котором вы спрашивали. Другое дело, что возможна двусмысленность, но это только лишний аргумент в пользу того, что от варианта "одни мама с дочкой" лучше отказаться.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97821/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus---------).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно, можно ещё вот так сказать: "Мама с дочкой одни". Это множественное число. Кстати, "скорее всего" - это вводное слово (в твоём предложении, бывает и частями речи: "Эта дорога скорее всего приведёт нас").

Answer (score 0):

Могут быть оба варианта, но у них разное значение (аж 3):

`Одна мама с дочкой` - тут число 1.

Пример: одна ручка с карандашами.

`Одни мама с дочкой` - тут в значении "сами" (одни в квартире).

В значении "некие" - `одни мама с дочкой` очень режет слух. Думаю, что в литературе так 100% не напишут. Потому что:

одна (кто?) мама (с кем?) с дочкой

Но можно: одни (кто?) мама и дочка.